# Python Multiprocessing - shared memory

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiprocessing

1. From the main process, I create 3 child processes and I pass an instance of a 'common' class...the same instance is passed to all 3 child processes.
2. This common class has a dictionary and a queue (which contains a lot of items)
3. These child processes retrieve 'items' from this queue
4. For these items, I call a REST service to get some data about the 'item'
5. I add this info to the "common" dictionary
6. There are no errors

However, when I try to access this dictionary from the main process, its empty.

Comment: Can you paste the code ?

Comment: I think the problem in the place of instantiation of the variable

Comment: the behaviour is expected. See [Python: Possible to share in-memory data between 2 separate processes](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1268252/4279)

Answer (score 0):

For sharing state between processes, the most flexible way is to use a [`multiprocessing.Manager`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes). You can also use e.g. `multiprocessing.Array`,  but that can only contain data of the same type.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your responses.

I managed to solve the problem using
multiprocessing.Manager().dict()

Is this the best way....I'm not entirely sure. I think I need to read a lot more on Multiprocessing.

What I find challenging is the fact that the multiprocessing module offers a lot of functionality and as a beginner, its quite challenging to know the right 'tools' to use for the job.

I started off with threads...then moved to Processes....then used Queues....then used Managers. But as I read more on this subject, I see Python has a lot more to offer.