# Force multiprocessing.Array to be created in memory instead of on disk

Tags: python, multiprocessing, shared-memory

I am using Python 3.4 on Linux. I want to create an array in RAM that will be shared by processes spawned by the `multiprocessing` module (i.e. shared memory). According to the documentation, this should be possible by using [`multiprocessing.Array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.Array). When I use

```
array = multiprocessing.Array('i', N)
```

Python creates a file in `/tmp`, zeroes it, and uses it through `mmap.mmap()` as shared memory (I have verified this by looking into `/usr/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/heap.py`). However, I would like the array to be created truly in memory, not on disk. The reason is that in my use case, `N` is very large (more than 100 GB), I have a lot of RAM but low disk capacity. The creation of `multiprocessing.Array()` thus ends with `IOError: No space left on device` because it uses a file on disk for the shared memory rather than RAM.

I was able to get around this by mounting a directory via `tmpfs` and setting `tempfile.tempdir` to point to this directory. However, is there an easier way? Why is Python creating shared memory in this way?

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is No. For the long answer, read this:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268252/python-possible-to-share-in-memory-data-between-2-separate-processes?lq=1)

You can always use os.fork() to pass a copy of the parent's memory to the child but can't actually share the address space.