# Poor man's Python data parallelism doesn't scale with the # of processors? Why?

Tags: python-2.7, parallel-processing

I'm needing to make many computational iterations, say 100 or so, with a very complicated function that accepts a number of input parameters. Though the parameters will be varied, each iteration will take nearly the same amount of time to compute. I found [this post](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/511474-run-function-in-separate-process/) by Muhammad Alkarouri. I modified his code so as to fork the script N times where I would plan to set N equal at least to the number of cores on my desktop computer.

It's an old MacPro 1,0 running 32-bit Ubuntu 16.04 with 18GB of RAM, and in none of the runs of the test file below does the RAM usage exceed about 15% (swap is never used). That's according to the System Monitor's Resources tab, on which it is also shown that when I try running 4 iterations in parallel all four CPUs are running at 100%, whereas if I only do one iteration only one CPU is 100% utilized and the other 3 are idling.  (Here are the [actual specs](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/mac_pro/specs/mac-pro-quad-2.66-specs.html) for the computer. And `cat /proc/self/status` shows a `Cpus_allowed` of 8, twice the total number of cpu cores, which may indicate hyper-threading.)

So I expected to find that the 4 simultaneous runs would consume only a little more time than one (and going forward I generally expected run times to pretty much scale in inverse proportion to the number of cores on any computer). However, I found to the contrary that instead of the running time for 4 being not much more than the running time for one, it is instead a bit more than twice the running time for one. For example, with the scheme presented below, a sample "time(1) real" value for a single iteration is 0m7.695s whereas for 4 "simultaneous" iterations it is 0m17.733s. And when I go from running 4 iterations at once to 8, the running time scales in proportion.

So my question is, why doesn't it scale as I had supposed (and can anything be done to fix that)? This is, by the way, for deployment on a few desktops; it doesn't have to scale or run on Windows.

Also, I have for now neglected the `multiprocessing.Pool()` alternative as my function was rejected as not being pickleable.

Here is the modified Alkarouri script, `multifork.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import os, cPickle, time

import numpy as np
np.seterr(all='raise')

def function(x):
    print '... the parameter is ', x
    arr = np.zeros(5000).reshape(-1,1)
    for r in range(3):
        for i in range(200):
            arr = np.concatenate( (arr, np.log( np.arange(2, 5002) ).reshape(-1,1) ), axis=1 )
    return { 'junk': arr, 'shape': arr.shape }

def run_in_separate_process(func, *args, **kwds):
    numruns = 4
    result = [ None ] * numruns
    pread = [ None ] * numruns
    pwrite = [ None ] * numruns
    pid = [ None ] * numruns
    for i in range(numruns):
        pread[i], pwrite[i] = os.pipe()
        pid[i] = os.fork()
        if pid[i] > 0:
            pass
        else: 
            os.close(pread[i])
            result[i] = func(*args, **kwds)
            with os.fdopen(pwrite[i], 'wb') as f:
                cPickle.dump((0,result[i]), f, cPickle.HIGHEST_PROTOCOL)
            os._exit(0)

    #time.sleep(17)
    while True:
        for i in range(numruns):
            os.close(pwrite[i])
            with os.fdopen(pread[i], 'rb') as f:
                stat, res = cPickle.load(f)
                result[i] = res
            #os.waitpid(pid[i], 0)
        if not None in result: break
    return result

def main():
    print 'Running multifork.py.'

    print run_in_separate_process( function, 3 )

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

With `multifork.py`, uncommenting `os.waitpid(pid[i], 0)` has no effect. And neither does uncommenting `time.sleep()` if 4 iterations are being run at once and if the delay is not set to more than about 17 seconds. Given that time(1) real is something like 0m17.733s for 4 iterations done at once, I take that to be an indication that the While True loop is not itself a cause of any appreciable inefficiency (due to the processes all taking the same amount of time) and that the 17 seconds are indeed being consumed solely by the child processes.

Out of a profound sense of mercy I have spared you for now my other scheme, with which I employed `subprocess.Popen()` in lieu of `os.fork()`. With that one I had to send the function to an auxiliary script, the script that defines the command that is the first argument of `Popen()`, via a file. I did however use the same While True loop. And the results? They were the same as with the simpler scheme that I am presenting here--- almost exactly.

Comment: 32-bit Ubuntu with 18GB of RAM?

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski it's not a problem in case of [using PAE](https://askubuntu.com/questions/20049/does-ubuntu-desktop-32bit-support-more-than-4gb-memory-with-default-installation#20050)

Comment: @ŁukaszRogalski, yes frist has it right. See also [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3_GB_barrier) on PAE. The 3GB is only for Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use [`joblib.Parallel`](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html#parallel-reference-documentation) feature?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from joblib import Parallel, delayed

import numpy as np
np.seterr(all='raise')

def function(x):
    print '... the parameter is ', x
    arr = np.zeros(5000).reshape(-1,1)
    for r in range(3):
        for i in range(200):
            arr = np.concatenate( (arr, np.log( np.arange(2, 5002) ).reshape(-1,1) ), axis=1 )
    return { 'junk': arr, 'shape': arr.shape }

def main():
    print 'Running multifork.py.'

    print Parallel(n_jobs=2)(delayed(function)(3) for _ in xrange(4))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

It seems that you have some bottleneck in your computations.

On your example you passes your data over the `pipe` which is not very fast method. To avoid this performance problem you should use shared memory. This is how `multiprocessing` and `joblib.Parallel` work.

Also you should remember that in single-thread case you don't have to serialize and deserialize the data but in case of multiprocess you have to.

Next, even if you have 8 cores it could be hyper-threading feature enabled with divides core performance into 2 threads, thus if you have 4 HW cores the OS things that there are 8 of them. There are a lot of advantages and disadvantages to use HT but the main thing is if you going to load all your cores to do some computations for a long time then you should disable it.

For example, I have a Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-2100 CPU @ 3.10GHz with 2 HW cores and HT enabled. So in `top` I saw 4 cores. The time of computations for me are:

- n_jobs=1 - 0:07.13
- n_jobs=2 - 0:06.54
- n_jobs=4 - 0:07.45

This is how my `lscpu` looks like:

```
Architecture:          x86_64
CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                4
On-line CPU(s) list:   0-3
Thread(s) per core:    2
Core(s) per socket:    2
Socket(s):             1
NUMA node(s):          1
Vendor ID:             GenuineIntel
CPU family:            6
Model:                 42
Stepping:              7
CPU MHz:               1600.000
BogoMIPS:              6186.10
Virtualization:        VT-x
L1d cache:             32K
L1i cache:             32K
L2 cache:              256K
L3 cache:              3072K
NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-3
```

Note at **Thread(s) per core** line.

So in your example there are not so many computations rather that data transfering. You application doesn't have time to get the advantages of parallelism. If you will have a long computation job (about 10 minutes) I think you will get it.

**ADDITION:**

I've taken a look at your function more detailed. I've replaced multiple execution with just one execution of `function(3)` function and run it within profiler:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v python -m cProfile so.py
```

Output if quite long, you can view full version here (http://pastebin.com/qLBBH5zU). But the main thing is that the program lives most of the time in `numpy.concatenate` function. You can see it:

```
ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
.........
600    1.375    0.002    1.375    0.002 {numpy.core.multiarray.concatenate}
.........
Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:01.64
.........
```

If you will run multiple instances of this program you will see that the time increases very much as the execution time of individual program instance. I've started 2 copy simultaneously:

```
$ /usr/bin/time -v python -m cProfile prog.py & /usr/bin/time -v python -m cProfile prog.py &
```

On the other hand I wrote a small fibo function:

```
def fibo(x):
    arr = (0, 1)
    for _ in xrange(x):
        arr = (arr[-1], sum(arr))
    return arr[0]
```

And replace the `concatinate` line with `fibo(10000)`. In this case the execution time of single-instanced program is `0:22.82` while the execution time of two instances takes almost the same time per instance (`0:24.62`).

Based on this I think perhaps numpy uses some shared resource which leads to parallization problem. Or it can be `numpy` or `scipy` -specific issue.

And the last thing about the code, you have to replace the block below:

```
for r in range(3):
    for i in range(200):
        arr = np.concatenate( (arr, np.log( np.arange(2, 5002) ).reshape(-1,1) ), axis=1 )
```

With the only line:

```
arr = np.concatenate( (arr, np.log(np.arange(2, 5002).repeat(3*200).reshape(-1,3*200))), axis=1 )
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the prompt response. I just now ran a test that consisted of making `func(*args, **kwds)` the first line of `run_in_separate_process()` and the second line `sys.exit()`. That eliminates the pipes and the serialization. And the answer with the `time` wrapper is 7.5 seconds versus 7.6 when I run the script as above with `numruns = 1'. Hence it does not seem to be the case that either the use of pipes or the serialization is the problem.

Comment: Regarding shared memory, I was discouraged by [the comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268252/python-possible-to-share-in-memory-data-between-2-separate-processes) by  Alex Martelli.

Comment: @MikeO'Connor, well done, but forking (creating) a new process is also performance issue, that's why `multiprocessing` recommends to use `Pool` which creates number of processes only once. Comparing to creating a thread it's more expensive operation.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I will try your joblib.Parallel code. But I will have to be away from the computer for a while.

Comment: I have discovered that the [processors](http://ark.intel.com/products/27218/Intel-Xeon-Processor-5150-4M-Cache-2_66-GHz-1333-MHz-FSB), there are two of them, are not ht'ed. `lscpu` reports 4 CPUs (meaning cores as there are physically a total of 4 cores, two in each of the two processors), as does `/proc/cpuinfo`. I used `taskset` to force CPU assignments so that each child process would get it's own CPU--- no improvement in run times.

Comment: I should add that `flags` in the `/proc/cpuinfo` output mysteriously includes `ht`, and `Cpus_allowed` is ff (eight); however `taskset` reports that the default mask prior to my setting it is f, meaning 4 processors (correct). I also bracketed the function call with `time.time()` calls and computed the elapsed time for each during parallel processing of three iterations. All were only slightly less than the total run time. So somehow just the fact that a function is being computed in a child process evidently makes it slower. (Encountering silly problems with `joblib` install. Working on it.)

Comment: @MikeO'Connor I've improved my answer, please take a look.

Comment: Thanks so much for the additional effort and I am thinking that it explains why I had to rather apologetically give an answer of my own (see below) to try to clear things up. The bewilderment of my answer was based on the fact that when I went on to put the code in my real project (not utterly trivial to do as my project is complex) I did not find the failure to scale. And in my project I don't do an concatenation until after the results have been accumulated in a list and the child processes have quit. You have explained that. I had already accepted your answer and given you a check mark.

Answer (score 1):

I am providing an answer here so as to not leave such a muddled record. First, I can report that most-serene frist's `joblib` code works, and note that it's shorter and that it also doesn't suffer from the limitations of the `While True` loop of my example, which only works efficiently with jobs that each take about the same amount of time. I see that the `joblib` project has current support and if you don't mind dependency upon a third-party library it may be an excellent solution. I may adopt it.

But, with my test function the time(1) real, the running time using the `time` wrapper, is about the same with either `joblib` or my poor man's code.

To answer the question of why the scaling of the running time in inverse proportion to the number of physical cores doesn't go as hoped, I had diligently prepared my test code that I presented here so as to produce similar output and to take about as long to run as the code of my actual project, per single-run without parallelism (and my actual project is likewise CPU-bound, not I/O-bound). I did so in order to test before undertaking the not-really-easy fitting of the simple code into my rather complicated project. But I have to report that in spite of that similarity, the results were much better with my actual project. I was surprised to see that I *did* get the sought inverse scaling of running time with the number of physical cores, more or less.

So I'm left supposing--- here's my tentative answer to my own question--- that perhaps the OS scheduler is fickle and very sensitive to the type of job. And there could be effects due to other processes that may be running even if, as in my case, the other processes are hardly using any CPU time (I checked; they weren't).

Tip #1: Never name your `joblib` test code `joblib.py` (you'll get an import error). Tip #2: Never rename your `joblib.py` file test code file and run the renamed file without deleting the `joblib.py` file (you'll get an import error).

Comment: Update: Please see @frist 's addition to his answer, and my comment in response. I had deliberately put concatenation in the function just to generate a time-wasting component (as I often have to do concatenation in numpy anyway and I wanted my trial code to be "realistic"). frist explains that numpy concatenation may be unavoidably inefficient when operating with parallel processes.

Comment: It's nice to see my old code used. Of course, now the use of `joblib.Parallel` or [multiprocessing.Pool](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers) is more appropriate.

Comment: @Muhammad Alkarouri  If you are doing functional-style programming in Python with stacked decorators... a very complicated function... and I am, you'll get an error to the effect that your function can't be pickled. I got that from joblib I recall and from something else, probably from `.Pool`. Nowadays I'm making use of [the Intel® Math Kernel Library](https://software.intel.com/en-us/distribution-for-python/features). It's free and doesn't have the pickling problem.