# modifying a variable of the parent process in the child process in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

when I define a variable on a module level, start a new subprocess and modify this variable in the child process, should the change be visible in the parent process? From my experiments, it seems that the answer is 'no' but I'm wandering if I am not missing something.

I'm trying to do this since I need to share large volumes of memory between the parent and child processes and `multiprocessing.Queue` is way too slow for my purposes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python: Possible to share in-memory data between 2 separate processes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268252/python-possible-to-share-in-memory-data-between-2-separate-processes)

Comment: No not unless you create the object once in another file and import it from there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python multiprocessing shared memory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124588/python-multiprocessing-shared-memory)

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, can you elaborate on this?