# Load large files to memory (persistently)

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, persistent-storage

I have a huge dictionary that weighs about 5GB, and I would like to keep it in memory for fast access later.
I am fine with it consuming RAM during that time, to accelerate the reading times.
The general scheme I am looking for is

```
script1.py

with open("some_really_big_file", 'rb') as handle:
    a = pickle.load(handle) --->Will take ~2 minutes

physical_memory_address = store_to_persistent_memory(a)

with open('memory_path', 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(physical_memory_address , handle)
```

```
script2.py

with open("memory_path", 'rb') as handle:
    mem_path = pickle.load(handle)

dict = load_persistent_memory(mem_path ) ---> Really fast
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Possible to share in-memory data between 2 separate processes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1268252/possible-to-share-in-memory-data-between-2-separate-processes)

Comment: So basically the first script should stay open, or without mmap.close() it stays in memory?

Comment: It might automatically be closed by the system, I really don't know.

Comment: Well, mmap doesn't seem to be the solution for the problem, as it's only virtually in memory, but when trying to query the object, the whole process of fetching it still occurs.